# kafka 3.4.0 sasl_PLAINTEXT kafka-metadata-quorum.sh Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake

Tags: apache-kafka

kafka 3.4.0 sasl_PLAINTEXT exec kafka-metadata-quorum.sh
Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.

1、kafka 3.4.0 config broker sasl_PLAINTEXT,

```
./kafka-metadata-quorum.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.3.138:9092 --command-config kafka_server_config.conf describe --status
```

kafkalog stdout :

```
[2023-05-30 16:21:36,542] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=BROKER, nodeId=2] Failed authentication with /192.168.3.138 (channelId=192.168.3.139:9092-192.168.3.138:36074-41) (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

2、kafka server server.properties config

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@192.168.3.138:9093,2@192.168.3.139:9093,3@192.168.3.140:9093
listeners=BROKER://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=BROKER
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=BROKER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT 
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
```

3、kafka_server_jaas.conf config

```
broker.KafkaServer { 
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret"
    user_admin="admin-secret"
    user_alice="alice-secret";
};
```

4、kafka_server_config.conf config

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="admin" \
    password="admin-secret";
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

5、 use kafka_server_config.conf create topic or descirbe topic info

```
[root@opensource01 kafka_2.13-3.4.0]# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic enmotech  --bootstrap-server 192.168.3.138:9092 --command-config kafka_server_config.conf
Topic: enmotech    TopicId: ZXVFSBuUT7e_xYWKk4rV9A    PartitionCount: 5    ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
    Topic: enmotech    Partition: 0    Leader: 3    Replicas: 3,1,2    Isr: 3,1,2
    Topic: enmotech    Partition: 1    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,3    Isr: 3,1,2
    Topic: enmotech    Partition: 2    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,3,1    Isr: 3,1,2
    Topic: enmotech    Partition: 3    Leader: 3    Replicas: 3,1,2    Isr: 3,1,2
    Topic: enmotech    Partition: 4    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,3    Isr: 3,1,2
```

PS： don't enable sasl_plaintext ,exec kafka-metadata-quorum.sh,the output is :

```
[root@opensource02 bin]# ./kafka-metadata-quorum.sh  --bootstrap-server 192.168.3.139:9092  describe --replication
NodeId    LogEndOffset    Lag    LastFetchTimestamp    LastCaughtUpTimestamp    Status      
1         96191           0      1685433493877         1685433493877            Leader      
2         96191           0      1685433493482         1685433493482            Follower    
3         96191           0      1685433493474         1685433493474            Follower
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same thing as you with pure SSL, I have a client certificate which has all admin rights on the cluster and the kafka-metadata-quorum.sh fails to authenticate. This could be a bug on the script. I can get all the information about the cluster with the admin client certificates, but just this script doesn't work and brokers throw authentication error logs.

It could be the weird argument passing of the script causes this, it asks for the --command-config first and then the other arguments. If you try to do

> ./kafka-metadata-quorum.sh --bootstrap-server <>:9092 describe --replication --command-config
> etc...

It does not understand the --command-config part and says its not recognized, but the above usage is the default for all kafka scripts when passing command configurations for security stuff. I think this should be investigated by kafka developers.

Comment: i see the org.apache.kafka.tools.MetadataQuorumCommand.java source code ,
use Utils.loadProps(commandConfig.getPath()) load kafka config file 
and i see the kafka.tools.ClusterTool.scala

      val configPath = namespace.getString("config")
      val properties = if (configPath == null) {
        new Properties()
      } else {
        Utils.loadProps(configPath)
      }

They use Utils.loadProps(configPath)  to load the configuration file

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14711